# Python numbers in a string to a symbol

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function that converts all digits in a string to underline. Please where have I gone wrong?

```
numbers = "1234567890"

string_input = str(input("Input a String? "))

print(string_input.replace(numbers, "_"))
```

Comment: Your code replaces the entire string `"1234567890"` (and *only* the entire string) with a single `'_'`. Are you familiar with the `in` operator? If so -- use it. There are more high-tech approaches (such as regular expressions or `string.translate`) but given your level of learning to program, just use a simple loop.

Comment: @MikeScotty Someone learning to program for the first time probably doesn't yet have the basic mental model needed to understand what they read. Your comment suggests that you have a mild case of the [curse of knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_knowledge) (which is of course much better than having the curse of ignorance :)).

Comment: @MikeScotty Brother, I am sorry I do not possess the programming knowledge you do. I am trying to learn Python but sometimes it's hard to know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
string = "There are 5, 7, 2, and 15 foobars"

numbers = ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")

for num in numbers:
    string = string.replace(num, "_")

# "There are _, _, _, and __ foobars"
print(string)
```

EDIT: alternative way

```
string = "There are 5, 7, 2, and 15 foobars"

for num in range(10):
    string = string.replace(str(num), "_")

# "There are _, _, _, and __ foobars"
print(string)
```

Comment: Thank you sir. This is exactly what i was after. I just had to add user input and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the string `"1234567890"`. I think what you want to do is replace every number in that string. So you would have to make a for loop and loop through every number in that string and replace it in the input string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generator expression:

```
string_input = input("Input a String? ")
print(''.join('_' if x in '0123456789' else x for x in string_input))
```

Or the regex library:

```
import re
string_input = input("Input a String? ")
print(re.sub('\d', '_', string_input))
```

---

Btw. `input(...)` already returns a string, so you don't need to convert it.